# How to make a class method only accesible by another class?

Tags: java

Suposse there are a "Worker" class in which one of its attributes is a queue of "WorkOrder" objects, and a "Boss" class which is the only one that can add or delete new "WorkOrders" of this queue. How could it be possible to make the method that modifies the queue only accessible by "Boss"?

I've thought of two solutions:

(a) Make the method package-private, keep the two classes in the same package and instantiate them in another.

(b) Make an interface with the methods that can be accessed by "Worker", make the constructor of this class private and create instead a static method which return an object with the same type than the interface.

What is your opinion? Can you think of a more elegant solution?

Comment: If the connection between these two classes is so strict, why don't you put the code into the same class?

Comment: I actually wish I could do this all the time. For example, only the game board can modify the position of a piece. I have 30 types of pieces, so I don't want them all to be inner classes. Moreover, I don't want the pieces to be able to modify the position of other pieces, so putting them all in the same package doesn't solve the issue. Unfortunately, I know of no way to do this in java.

Comment: @C-Otto Well, actually the connection is not that strict. That's their only connection, and I need both classes for different things.

Comment: What about moving the other stuff away into dedicated classes, and having a single class dealing with the code of your question? "Separation of concerns" and "Single Resposibility Principle" come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Consider having an interface that exposes the worker methods you want to be public. The boss can hold a reference to the implementation (which has the workorders queue getter) and only present the interface to other classes.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;

class Class {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Boss boss = new Boss();
    final Worker worker = boss.getWorker("sivmish");
    worker.getWorkItems();//ERROR: only Boss has access to this.
  }
}

interface Worker {
  void processWork();
}

interface WorkOrder {
  void doWork();
}

class WorkerImpl implements Worker {
  private final Queue<WorkOrder> workItems;

  WorkerImpl() {
    this.workItems = new ArrayDeque<>();
  }

  public Queue<WorkOrder> getWorkItems() {
    return workItems;
  }

  @Override
  public void processWork() {
    while (!workItems.isEmpty()) {
      workItems.poll().doWork();
    }
  }
}

class Boss {
  private final Map<String, WorkerImpl> workersByName;

  Boss() {
    workersByName = new HashMap<String, WorkerImpl>();
  }

  public Worker getWorker(final String name, WorkOrder... workOrders) {
    if (!workersByName.containsKey(name)) {
      final WorkerImpl worker = new WorkerImpl();
      workersByName.put(name, worker);
    }
    final WorkerImpl worker = workersByName.get(name);
    worker.getWorkItems().addAll(Arrays.asList(workOrders));
    return worker;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to keep the queue inside the Boss class,because you want to make it only accessible by the Boss for adding or removing

```
class Boss
    {
    public LinkedList<E> queue = new LinkedList<E>(); 
    private void add(item)
    {
    //do stuff...
    }
    private void remove()
    {//do stuff...}
    public static void viewOnly()
    {
      //display details
    }

}

class Workers
    { 
          public workers() 
          {
             Boss.viewOnly();
          }
    }

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
     {    
          Boss b = new Boss();
            b.add(1); //job 1
            b.add(5); //job 5
               /* and so on..

              */
        workers w = new workers();
    }
}
```